# Qgis2threejs changing rotation point

Tags: visualisation, qgis2threejs, offset, rotate

I am new to QGis and have an issue with the QGis2threejs plugin. I am trying and searching already for some hours, but couldn't find an answer for this - I hope it's not something obvious. If yes, sorry about this.

I have created a new project (QGis 3.24 and QGis2threejs 2.18 - same issue with 2.16) with XYZ Tile Bing Area and also loaded a layer. When I now open QGis2threejs I am able to visualize the 3D model and also navigate around there. However, when the model gets rotated, it seems to rotate a point which is far below the surface. This means, when rotating, the model is always going outside the visible window.

Is there a possibility to change the "rotation point" (not sure what the correct terminology is) to e.g. somewhere in the middle of the surface? That would make it easier for me to view the surface from different angles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way! It took me quite a while but here it is:

- Click on a new rotation point, a small yellow dot will appear
- A panel will also appear on the left, click on orbit and QUICKLY click on it again to stop the rotation. The new rotation point will be active.

It will take a few time to acquire this but it is the only way I found.